# Ruby delete_if block

Tags: arrays, ruby, block

This is using Ruby 1.9.

I have a delete_if block:

```
@logHash[date].delete_if{ | logItem | logItem.name == name }
```

Where `logItem.name` is the name of the `logItem` and `name` is the name of the `logItem` I'm looking for. This works fine, except it deletes each `logItem` with the specified `name`. Is there a way to find the first item with an equal `name` and only delete that? So if there are two logItems that have the same `name`, I only want to delete one of them. Any ideas?

Comment: You're asking about an array, not a hash, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `Array#index` to find the index of the first item which had a matching name, and then `Array#delete_at` to delete it.

```
index_to_delete = @logHash[date].index {|log_item| log_item.name == name}
@logHash[date].delete_at(index_to_delete)
```